# How to get the stats of a post using post ID from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get stats (likes, comments, shares) of a Facebook post. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Url: `https://graph.facebook.com/<userid>_<postid>` - there is a plenty of information about the wall post.

`http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer` - you can use this tool for testing.

Sample data:

```
{
  "id": "<userid>_<postid>", 
  "from": {
    "name": "User Name", 
    "id": "<userid>"
  }, 
  "message": "playing with graph api", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/<userid>/posts/<postid>"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/<userid>/posts/<postid>"
    }
  ], 
  "privacy": {
    "description": "Public", 
    "value": "EVERYONE"
  }, 
  "type": "status", 
  "created_time": "2012-03-14T11:33:14+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2012-03-14T11:33:14+0000", 
  "comments": {
    "count": 0
  }, 
  "is_published": true
}
```

Comment: How I can get `postId` cz when I post on wall it return only `true` not the postId

Comment: How do you make a post? Using http `POST` to `/me/feed`?

Comment: I am using fb API
`FB.api(
                  {
                    method: 'status.set',
                    status: status1
                  },`

Comment: Ah. You are using an deprecated REST API. I strongly suggest replace this method with Graph API. `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/` check out this link, look for an example for the method `/me/feed`

Comment: Ok. Now I am using graph API but still there is a problem to get link of that post. When I make a post on facebook wall. How I can get the link of that post in respone

Comment: You'll get a post id from `/me/feed`, and then you can make a link: `http://www.facebook.com/<user>/posts/<post id>`

Comment: Its fine. I got it. I will pick the top most post but meanwhile if there become another post or due to any reason my connection  losts then there can be a null or a wrong id in database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8912/discussion-between-rana-muhammad-usman-and-deadrunk)

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `https://graph.facebook.com/<postid>` if it is a status.
You can get the postid by clicking on the date/time in your feed.

If the type is a comment then you can use 
`https://graph.facebook.com/<postid>_<commentid>`